# Formula for Ascending Sequence

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to help someone generate a formula to return a simple sequential series of values.  For example in cell **C6** we inserted the formula:

```
=ROW(A1)
```

and in cell **D6** we inserted the formula:

```
=ROWS($1:1)
```

When we copy these cells downward, we get:

[image]

The problem arises when he attempts to insert or delete a row well above the column of formulas.  For example when row # **3** is deleted we get:

[image]

Both columns **C** and **D** are no longer valid.  What's more, re-inserting the row does not restore the sequence either!

Is there an alternative formula that is not sensitive to deleting or inserting rows above the sequence ??

**EDIT#1:**

This is how the sequence is being used:

[image]

Column **C** contains the list of the items from column **B** that need to be sampled.  The formula in **E6** *(when copied down)* retrieves the samples.

All is good until a row above the header row is inserted or deleted.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a reason you are using the row number as your reference.  Is there a reason?  There are many ways to get a sequence of numbers, having a better understanding why you are doing this would help find the right one.

Comment: After the sequence is generated, get rid of the formula. Simply select and copy the data generated thru formula, and replace it with 'paste special values'

Comment: @Paul  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Wishwas  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: You can use `ROW() - MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(E:E<>"",),0)`  but this requires that all the cells above not have anything in them.  Or you can use the title of the column in the Match instead; `ROW() - MATCH("Samples", E:E,0)`

Comment: Or if you know that the header row will never be deleted then `ROW() - ROW($E$5)`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Merely start your row counter at such a level that you know that rows within the row range will not be deleted.  eg: Instead of `ROWS($1:1)`, use  `ROWS($10:10)`

Comment: @ScottCraner  Thanks........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer with screenshots.

I changed both formulas to use rows in a range that would not be deleted.  It is not entirely bulletproof, but should work well depending on the range you select.

And if you re-insert the missing row, the formulas will re-adjust, but the proper count will remain.

## Before deletion

[image]

### After deleting Row 3

[image]